# What data compression did Donkey Kong Country use?

Tags: nintendo, game-cartridge, snes, compression

Donkey Kong Country was among the most ambitious, popular and influential of Super Nintendo games. Technically, its big trick was taking animations rendered on Silicon Graphics workstations and putting them on the cartridge to be displayed as SNES sprites.

The cartridge was 32 megabits (4 MB). That was pretty big for a fourth-generation game cartridge, and ROM chips were a significant contributing factor to total cost. If I were the developer, I would have tried very hard to compress the animations, background images and other data on the cartridge, decompressing them into console RAM for use. I'm sure the developers at the time must've thought of it.

What data compression techniques did they use?

Comment: Not an answer, but [here is a post-mortem](https://all-things-andy-gavin.com/2011/02/02/making-crash-bandicoot-part-1/) of another 3-D game, also pre-rendered on SGI workstations, released for another console at the same time

Comment: In particular, part 3 of the *Crash Bandicoot* war story talks about how they did it for that game.

Comment: A speculation, thus not an answer: there are two factors to consider - the memory consumption for decompression must be relatively low, thus complex Markov model-based algorithms are out; and, at the time, several efficient LZ algorithms, as well as arithmetic coding, were still under patents. Thus, a homebrew quick-and-dirty variant of a LZ family algorithm is likely.

Comment: @LeoB. Was avoiding patent fees a higher priority than getting a better compression routine that works, right away? Especially one that’s willing to pay for $100K IRIX workstations in the ’90s?

Comment: @Davislor A one-off price of $100K is peanuts for a large company - it's only the salary of one or two employees. Not to mention that the parent company NEC was marketing its own supercomputers in the 1980s so they most likely already had some SGI kit already. On the other hand a license fee payable for every cartridge sold is a direct hit on the profits from that game.

Comment: @alephzero I was thinking along the lines of avoiding license fees per item sold.

Comment: @Davislor As alephzero said, *a license fee payable for every cartridge sold is a direct hit on the profits from that game*.

Comment: sounds like custom decompression was used (the SNES CPU is a 16-bit 6502 like), check out disassembly here: https://github.com/p4plus2/DKC2-disassembly

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It is an interesting LZ variant: there is a mechanism to allow references to arbitrary locations of the decompressed stream, as opposed to the usual "window".

Comment: I remember reading in a video game magazine at the time of DKCs release that it was using some compression technique called something like "ANC", "AMC", ACN" or something like that.

Comment: @Davislor Crash Bandicoot isn’t prerendered; the PlayStation generates all pixels from geometry every frame. That blog just explains how polygon visibility was precomputed.

Comment: @Tommy The pixels were not what were-pre-rendered, yes. Unlike a modern 3-D game, which lets you move the camera around and alter the environment, *Crash Bandicoot* pre-calculated which polygons would appear on the screen on each frame. I think that’s what we’re both saying.

Comment: @Davislor yeah, I’m probably being pedantic but e.g. Quake’s BSP trees include a potentially visible set in each leaf node, i.e. a precomputed list of which other convex subsections of the map can possibly be visible from the current. And you’d never attach the ‘prerendered’ label to the geometry of Quake. Though you might to the lightmaps so hairs are being split.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the search engine results discuss compressing ROM files rather than how developers used techniques, algorithms, or special cart hardware to account for space limitations. MVG (Modern Vintage Gamer) has some really insightful videos regarding titles toward the end of the SNES' life that used tricks to crank out titles that went head to head with PSX ports at the time (Street Fighter Alpha 3 is a great example of this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fB9GlZUYNUQ&t=8s).

1 or 2 specialized cartridge chips were created for realtime/fast decompression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Super_NES_enhancement_chips this was used in SA2 as mentioned above). CRT technology displayed low-resolution images quite well, so the lack of fidelity was not as jarring as when you display titles like DKC/Killer Instinct on panel tech. The cartoonish models they used were simple enough to translate well into 16-bit sprites. DKC2 and 3 appear to have some custom compression algorithms documented in various places online (google is your friend here). For the most part though, some wise choices are able to keep even some of the largest games under the 4MB ceiling.